# $\operatorname{E}[X]\in\mathbb{R}\Rightarrow \operatorname{E}[e^{Xt}] \in\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, expectation, moment-generating-functions

$\operatorname{E}[e^{Xt}]$ is the moment generating function of $X$, which is either a discrete or continuous random variable. Is $\operatorname{E}[X]\in\mathbb{R}\Rightarrow \operatorname{E}[e^{Xt}] \in\mathbb{R}$ correct? If not, are there any circumstances under which it is correct?

Comment: When you say "$\in\mathbb{R}$", do you mean to emphasise that it's finite, or non-complex?

Comment: That it is finite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope: Let $X$ have pdf $x^{-3}\mathbb{I}[|x|>1]$. Then $X$ has mean $0$, but $\mathbb{E}[\exp(tX)]=\infty$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}-0$.

In general, it's hard to guarantee the existence of $\mathbb{E}[\exp(tX)]$ - one can have finite moments of arbitrarily large order without necessarily having the MGF finite for any nonzero $t$. One can even have moments of *all* orders without the MGF existing for any nonzero $t$ - consider the lognormal distribution as described in Mark's answer elsewhere on this page.

Comment: You can, the LogNormal does.

Comment: @Mark thanks - saw your answer come up just as I finished editing. will make a note. +1

Answer (score 4):

[This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32706/existence-of-the-moment-generating-function-and-variance) may be a good resource on mgf's.

The short answer is no, and a specific counterexample is the [log-normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) distribution.

We say that $X$ is Log-Normal if $X = e^Y$ where $Y$ is normally distributed.  It can be shown that:
$$E[X^n] = e^{n\mu+\frac{1}{2}n^2\sigma^2}$$
Despite this, $E[e^{tX}]$ diverges for any positive $t$, so the mgf is undefined despite all moments being defined (and finite).